# excel automation c#

Tags: c#, excel, automation

I am trying to create excel order form which will have price and qty columns and customer will put the values in the qty column and excel will update order cost column. problem i am facing right now is that number of columns in excel file is changing i.e. user can select multiple columns. so price column location is different every time 
  how to put formula in the column in order cost column to reference product price column

Answer (score 0):

If your qty column has a fixed column title, you could find it out by iterating the first row, and than use that information to correctly position the order cost formula.

But, it's hard to give a useful answer if you don't provide any more info, example of your tables or code...

Comment: I am generating excel file with products on each row & product info(name, supplier, dimentions etc) in columns.user of the application may not want to put all of product information in xls file for each customer. so he can unselect some columns so order excel file wont print those columns. this excel file will always have <b> product cost</b> and <b>qty to order</b> columns i want to put a formula in a column which will show order value for each product. i dont know how can i access price column and qtyorder column and put that formula in another column while i am generating that file.

Comment: Edit your question and post some code how are you generating excel file now - that way I can tell you where to put what. Otherwise, we're going to spend a lot of time in q/a about how to do it...